# Vagrant shell incompatible with foreground "server boot" commands

Tags: shell, vagrant

I'm running a shell script on `vagrant up` via the inline shell config of a Vagrantfile. One of the commands starts up a tomcat web server which normally runs in the foreground.

My dilemma is that a) the commands in the vagrant shell script should exit or run in the background so that the prompt returns to the user correct, and b) if I send the output to the background with `&` the output isn't visible and the user has no idea when the web server has finished booting.

I either need a way to send output to the background and tell the user when the server has booted, or a way to send to the background *once* the server has booted. Without messing with the maven/tomcat side I don't see a way to do it.

```
$script = <<-SCRIPT
    # other commands here
    mvn tomcat7:run &
SCRIPT

config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script, privileged: false, run: "always"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `nohup` command for this and redirect the output of the command in the specific log file - It does not fully answer the *and tell the user when the server has booted*

here's an example of a command I run

```
nohup java -jar /test/selenium-server-standalone-$1.jar -role hub &> /home/vagrant/nohup.grid.out&
```

If from the provisioning shell you'd want to give as much as possible information to the user, you could use sleep like 5/10 seconds (depending your deployment) then run `tail -20 <log_file>` so that would give users a good status of the progress of the task

Comment: Good idea. The sleep/tail method works and at least conveys to the user when the server has finished booting. Unfortunately there's no way to know for sure how long to run the loop - if it's too short the user won't see the end and if it's too long the console takes too long to return. But this is better than nothing.